# cakephp $this->Model->save() not updating

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to build an array and update a few fields in a loop.

This is my request->data

```
Array

(
    [list] => Array
        (
            [4] => null
            [2] => null
            [3] => null
            [5] => 3
        )

)
```

It's the return value from a jquery serialized list. The key being the row id and the value being the rows parent_id.

So I loop through the array in the controller:

```
foreach ($this->request->data['list'] as $key => $value) {
    (!isset($orders[$value])) ? $orders[$value]=0 : $orders[$value]++;
    $data = array('id' => $key, 'parent_id' => (int)$value, 'display_order' => $orders[$value]);
    $this->Category->save($data);
}
```

The $data array that I create in the loop is correct but the sql logs only shows SELECT COUNT(*) etc. for each row and no UPDATE commands.

I have tried all manner of ways to save this: using set() method, using $this->Category->id = $key; instead of directly adding the key in the data array.

Any ideas why this is not saving? I'm sure it is something simple...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think u forgot the cake convention in the save method, you have to put all the field values inside an array with the Model name FirstCap too, something like this:

```
Array
(
    [ModelName] => Array
        (
            [fieldname1] => 'value'
            [fieldname2] => 'value'
        )
)
```

Else you can use set for each and every value, and also youre forgetting to create one row for  every insert youre making so try something like this:

```
foreach ($this->request->data['list'] as $key => $value) {
     (!isset($orders[$value])) ? $orders[$value]=0 : $orders[$value]++;
     $data = array( 'Category' => array('id' => $key, 'parent_id' => (int)$value, 'display_order' => $orders[$value]));
     $this->Category->save($data);
}
```

Also you can set each and every id and then iterates over the values

```
foreach ($this->request->data['list'] as $key => $value) {
     (!isset($orders[$value])) ? $orders[$value]=0 : $orders[$value]++;
    $this->Category->id = $key;
    $this->Category->set(array('parent_id' => (int)$value,
                               'display_order' => $orders[$value]
    ));

     $this->Category->save();
}
```

try each and every answer but i think the last one will fit better at your problem.

Comment: I had tried all of these suggestions before posting the question but in the end your last suggestion worked. Although when I tried it I was not using (int) before $value the db column being NOT NULL didn't save when presented with a null value.

Answer (score 1):

From the CakePHP [book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html).

> When calling save in a loop, don’t forget to call create().

Answer (score 0):

echo $data and match it with  save() method's  syntax.also do not slip to match data types of fields in table.